# Buttons do not appear in my GUI when opening a new window in a new class

Tags: java, eclipse, class, user-interface, jbutton

I am making a vocabulary quiz program and when they click an option, a new window is supposed to pop up saying if they got it right or wrong. That works, but what doesn't show is the button in the window when it gives you the option to go back to the quiz, ruining the chance to continue onto the next question, or even worse, answering the current question.

Here is the main quiz code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;


public class SAT extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JButton buttonA; 
private JButton buttonB;
private JButton buttonC;
private JButton buttonD;
private JPanel panel1;
private JFrame frame1;
private JTextField Text1;
private JLabel label1;

public static final String POOP = "Words3.xls"; //everywhere that there is POOP is the excel sheet
public static String read1(int rowIndex, int colIndex, int a)
{   
    String value = new String();
    HSSFWorkbook wb = null;

    try {
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(POOP));
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

    String sheet2=null;//placeholder
    if (a==1){sheet2="SAT";}//one of these for each sheet
    if (a==2){sheet2="Test";}
    if (a==3){sheet2="vwlvlHU1";}

    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheet2);
    HSSFRow row=sheet.getRow(rowIndex-1);
    HSSFCell cell=row.getCell(colIndex-1);

    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);

    return value;
}

private static void saveWorkbook(HSSFWorkbook wb) throws IOException
{
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(POOP);
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
}

public static int RNG1(int a) { //this RNG is used to find the word and random definitions
    //RNG code:
    int min=1;//1
    int max=100;//number of flash cards, highest number, this is a placeholder
    if (a==1){max=253;}//we will have one of these statements for each set
    if (a==2){max=20;}
    if (a==3){max=40;}
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min + 1;//the +1 is so it doesn't choose header, maybe remove
        return randomNum;
    }
public static int RNG2(int b) {//this RNG will be used to determine which button gets true definition
    //RNG code:
    int min=1;//1
    int max=4;//number of options
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

//FIND THE WORD AND POS
int a=1;//tells methods to look in right set
int rowIndex=RNG1(a);//here is where a random word, pos, and def will be called for
int colIndex=1;//use colIndex=1 to show word
String WORD=read1(rowIndex,colIndex,a);//to pull word
//System.out.println("Word: "+WORD);
int colIndexPOS=2;//POS=part of speech/colIndexPOS=2 for part of speech
String POS=read1(rowIndex,colIndexPOS,a);
//System.out.println("Part of speech: "+POS);


int b=1;//placeholder
int location=RNG2(b);
//if location=1, put it in button 1 and have random definitions for other 3
//if location=2... same for 3 and 4

private String def(){
//TRUE DEFINITION:
int colIndexDEF=3;//DEF= definition/colIndexPOS=3 for definitions
String DEF=read1(rowIndex,colIndexDEF,a);
return DEF;

}
//FAKE DEFINITIONS:

//fake def 1:
private String rdef1(){//THIS BLOCK HAS AN ISSUE. SHOULD NOT BE DIVIDED BY CURLY BRACES BUT IT IS AN ERROR IF THEY ARE NOT THERE. MAYBE MAKE IT A METHOD?
int rowIndex1=0;//null value
int colIndexDEF=3;
String weirdo="WHY";
do{
rowIndex1=RNG1(a);
weirdo=read1(rowIndex1, colIndexPOS, a);
}while(rowIndex1==rowIndex || !weirdo.equals(POS));
String RANDDEF1=read1(rowIndex1, colIndexDEF, a);
return RANDDEF1;
}

//fake def 2:
private String rdef2(){//FIX DOWHILE
int rowIndex2=1;//null value
int colIndexDEF=3;
String POSsave1=null;
//do{
rowIndex2=RNG1(a);
POSsave1=read1(rowIndex2, colIndexPOS, a);
//}while(rowIndex2==rowIndex1 || rowIndex2==rowIndex || !POSsave1.equals(POS));
String RANDDEF2=read1(rowIndex2, colIndexDEF, a);
return RANDDEF2;
}

//fake def 3:
private String rdef3(){//FIX DOWHILE
int rowIndex3=1;//null value
int colIndexDEF=3;
String POSsave2=null;
//do{
rowIndex3=RNG1(a);
POSsave2=read1(rowIndex3, colIndexPOS, a);
//}while(rowIndex3==rowIndex || rowIndex3==rowIndex2 || rowIndex3==rowIndex1 || !POSsave2.equals(POS));
String RANDDEF3=read1(rowIndex3, colIndexDEF, a);
return RANDDEF3;
}


private void createButtonA() {
    String definition=null;
    if (location==1){
    definition=def();
    }
    if (location==2){
    definition=rdef1();
    }
    if (location==3){
    definition=rdef2();
    }
    if (location==4){
    definition=rdef3();
    }
    buttonA = new JButton(definition);

    add(buttonA);
    buttonA.setContentAreaFilled(false);  
    buttonA.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);//this allows an action to be performed when the button is pressed
    buttonA.setForeground(Color.blue);

    buttonA.setBounds(45,130,295,25);


}
private void createButtonB() {

    String definitionB=null;
    if (location==1){
    definitionB=rdef1();
    }
    if (location==2){
    definitionB=def();
    }
    if (location==3){
    definitionB=rdef3();
    }
    if (location==4){
    definitionB=rdef2();
    }
    buttonB = new JButton(definitionB);
    add(buttonB);
    buttonB.setContentAreaFilled(false);  
    buttonB.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);//this allows an action to be performed when the button is pressed
    buttonB.setForeground(Color.blue);
    buttonB.setBounds(45,95,295,25);
}
private void createButtonC() {
    String definitionC=null;
    if (location==1){
    definitionC=rdef2();
    }
    if (location==2){
    definitionC=rdef3();
    }
    if (location==3){
    definitionC=def();
    }
    if (location==4){
    definitionC=rdef1();
    }
    buttonC = new JButton(definitionC);
    add(buttonC);
    buttonC.setContentAreaFilled(false);  
    buttonC.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);//this allows an action to be performed when the button is pressed
    buttonC.setForeground(Color.blue);  

    buttonC.setBounds(45,60,295,25);
}
private void createButtonD() {
    String definitionD=null;
    if (location==1){
    definitionD=rdef3();
    }
    if (location==2){
    definitionD=rdef2();
    }
    if (location==3){
    definitionD=rdef1();
    }
    if (location==4){
    definitionD=def();
    }
    buttonD = new JButton(definitionD);
    add(buttonD);
    buttonD.setContentAreaFilled(false);  
    buttonD.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);//this allows an action to be performed when the button is pressed
    buttonD.setForeground(Color.blue);

    buttonD.setBounds(45,25,295,25);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SAT frameTable = new SAT();

    //frameTable.SAT();  //Creating Frame

    frameTable.createButtonA();  //Creating Button 1
    frameTable.createButtonB(); //Creating Button 2
    frameTable.createButtonC();//Creating button 3
    frameTable.createButtonD();//Creating button 3


}

public SAT() {//problem
    Container window = getContentPane();

    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout() ); //using the FlowLayout manager

    setSize(400,250); //setting the size of the initial box

    setVisible(true); //allows for manual size changing of the box

    setTitle("FlaQuiZ"); //Title for the GUI

    window.setBackground(Color.white);

    setLocation(500,280);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Allows us to actually exit when we click the "X"

    panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

    add(new JLabel("Choose the option that best fits this word: "+WORD));


    //add(new JLabel(""));

}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent i) {


    if ( location==1 && i.getSource() == buttonA || location==2 && i.getSource()==buttonB || location==3 && i.getSource()==buttonC || location==4 && i.getSource()==buttonD) { 
     GRATS congrats =new GRATS();
        congrats.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
    else{
        NO bad =new NO();
        bad.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }

    }

}
```

And then here would be the code if they got it wrong, where the button should appear to give the option to go back:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class NO extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JButton NOB;
private JPanel panel3;

public NO() { 



    Container window = getContentPane();

    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout() ); //using the FlowLayout manager

    setSize(275,160); //setting the size of the initial box

    setVisible(true); //allows for manual size changing of the box

    setTitle("Flaquiz"); //Title for the GUI

    window.setBackground(Color.white);

    setLocation(500,280);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Allows us to actually exit when we click the "X"

    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

    add(new JLabel("Uh oh, you got it wrong!"));

    //add(new JLabel(""));

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NO bad = new NO();
    //frameTable.SAT();    //Creating Frame
   bad.createbuttonNOB();  //Creating Button 1
}

private void createbuttonNOB() {

    NOB = new JButton("Go Back");
    add(NOB);
    NOB.setContentAreaFilled(false);  
    NOB.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);//this allows an action to be performed when the button is pressed
    NOB.setForeground(Color.blue);  
    NOB.setBounds(45,45,45,45);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent i) {
    if (i.getSource() == NOB ) { 
     SAT goback =new SAT();
        goback.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Protip: instead of commenting every line try to name your functions and variables well enough that it is easy to tell what they do

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but it seems you add the button directly to the JFrame even though you have a JPanel occupying the whole frame. Why not add the button to the JPanel?

Side Note: In the NO constructor, SetVisible doesn't determine whether or not you can manually change size. That's controlled by things like SetMaximumSize, SetMinimumSize, and SetResizable.